# java.lang.VerifyError: org/bouncycastle/asn1/x500/X500Name

Tags: java, eclipse, x509certificate

I am trying to create a signature from a cer file. Below is the code that I have used. I get an error on X500Name initialization. In debug mode the code works but when I export the code as a jar file using ant build, it gives the error. I have used two libraries that I have zipped with the exported jar 
a. bcprov-jdk15on-1.50.jar
b. bcpkix-jdk15on-1.50.jar

```
        X509Certificate[] certs = (X509Certificate[]) request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate");
        X500Name issuer = null;
        try{
         issuer = new X500Name(certs[0].getIssuerX500Principal().toString());
        }catch(Throwable e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Error:

```
 07:50:43,095 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8443-1) java.lang.VerifyError: org/bouncycastle/asn1/x500/X500Name
07:50:43,095 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8443-1)  at com.adobe.livecycle.usermanager.sslauthprovider.SSLMutualAuthProvider.authenticate(SSLMutualAuthProvider.java:139)
07:50:43,095 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8443-1)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
07:50:43,095 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8443-1)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
07:50:43,095 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8443-1)  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
07:50:43,095 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8443-1)  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
07:50:43,095 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8443-1)  at com.adobe.idp.dsc.component.impl.DefaultPOJOInvokerImpl.invoke(DefaultPOJOInvokerImpl.java:118)
07:50:43,095 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8443-1)  at com.adobe.idp.dsc.interceptor.impl.InvocationInterceptor.intercept(InvocationInterceptor.java:140)
07:50:43,095 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8443-1)  at com.adobe.idp.dsc.interceptor.impl.RequestInterceptorChainImpl.proceed(RequestInterceptorChainImpl.java:60)
07:50:43,095 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8443-1)  at com.adobe.idp.dsc.interceptor.impl.DocumentPassivationInterceptor.intercept(DocumentPassivationInterceptor.java:53)
07:50:43,096 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8443-1)  at com.adobe.idp.dsc.interceptor.impl.RequestInterceptorChainImpl.proceed(RequestInterceptorChainImpl.java:60)
07:50:43,096 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8443-1)  at com.adobe.idp.dsc.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.doInTransaction(TransactionInterceptor.java:74)
07:50:43,096 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8443-1)  at com.adobe.idp.dsc.transaction.impl.ejb.adapter.EjbTransactionCMTAdapterBean.execute(EjbTransactionCMTAdapterBean.java:357)
07:50:43,099 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8443-1)  at com.adobe.idp.dsc.transaction.impl.ejb.adapter.EjbTransactionCMTAdapterBean.doSupports(EjbTransactionCMTAdapterBean.java:227)
07:50:43,101 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8443-1)  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor479.invoke(Unknown Source)
07:50:43,102 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8443-1)  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
07:50:43,103 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8443-1)  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
07:50:43,104 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8443-1)  at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
07:50:43,105 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8443-1)  at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
07:50:43,105 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8443-1)  at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53)
07:50:43,106 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8443-1)  at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
07:50:43,107 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8443-1)  at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
07:50:43,107 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8443-1)  at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53)
07:50:43,108 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8443-1)  at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
07:50:43,108 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8443-1)  at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
07:50:43,109 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8443-1)  at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43)
07:50:43,110 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8443-1)  at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
07:50:43,111 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8443-1)  at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47)
07:50:43,112 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8443-1)  at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
```